# position:fixed not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, widget, blogger, css-position

I've added a new widget to my blog http://kasperikoski.blogspot.fi, which basically works as a menu by using "Add HTML/Script". The code is to bloggers HTML/CSS:

```
    .menukadn   {
    line-height: 1;
    }

    a.limeka, a.limeka:visited, a.limeka:active {
    font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: color 150ms linear;
    letter-spacing: -0.090em;
    }

    a.limeka:hover  {
    color: #21a97e;
    transition: color 150ms linear;
    }
```

And to the WIDGET:

```
    <div class="menukadn">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Kadnnn" class="limeka" title="" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="http://instagram.com/kasperikoski" class="limeka" title="" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
    </div>
```

When I try to add positioning like this,

```
    .menukadn   {
    line-height: 1;
    position: fixed;
    }
```

or alternativly to the widget DIV#HTML1 to itself:

```
    #HTML1 {
    position: fixed;
    }
```

it works perfectly at Mozilla Firefox but in Chrome my widget #HTML1 is located approximatly 800px right from where it should be (column-left-outer), just next to inner bodys left border. Any ideas that could there be some other code causing contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

Other than it's positioning `position:fixed` you haven't defined the position of the element e.g.

```
#HTML1 {
   position: fixed;
   left:0;
   top:0;
}
```

If you'd like to position it in relation to the screen width, you could try something like that:

```
#HTML1 {
   position: fixed;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   width: 200px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

The only drawback is that you **have** to define a width, after that, play with `left` or `right` until you have it where you want.

Comment: no, that didn't work either, because now its top left corner. I should be relative only from top, but still just next to inner body's left border. So same horizontal positioning on inner body despite screen resolution.

Comment: the `top:0; left:0` were just an example. You should define the position as it suits you.

Comment: Sir, you are my hero, heroine! Thank you! Now we're talking! But oh, still no cigar with IE but doesn't matter :)